# Server connection failure/useEffect in react

Tags: javascript, server

I'm having a problem connecting to my server in my *index.js*

I'm making an axios request:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios.get("/api/posts").then(res => {
        setPosts(res.data);
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [posts]);
```

my *server/index.js* has this endpoint...`app.get("/api/posts", getPosts);`

I have my proxy set up "proxy": "http://localhost:4000". This error shows up:

> http://localhost:3000/api/posts 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Your post says the proxy is at "localhost: **4000**", but the error message says "localhost: **3000**". Is this the cause of your problem, or just a typo?

Comment: I'm using React. The default port for React is 3000, so im supposed to be hitting a route in my server that is listing on port 4000, so i can get to "/api/posts"

Comment: I think you need to send proxy configuration as parameter to get request. something like this. `var config = { proxy: { host: proxy.ip, port: proxy.port } };
axios.get(url, config).then()`

Comment: Where you able to resolve your problem? @Yousuf Daramay